# SQL - error code 1005 with error number 121

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1005

I'm running the following MySQL query (trimmed down), generated automatically by *MySQL Workbench* and I get the following error:

> Error Code: 1005
> Can't create table 'regula.reservation' (errno: 121)

I'm not very proficient with databases and this error is not very informative.

What is the problem here?

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `regula`.`Users`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `regula`.`Users` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `regula`.`Users` (
  `idUsers` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `name` TEXT NOT NULL ,
  `type` TEXT NOT NULL ,
  `pwd` TEXT NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idUsers`) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `idUsers_UNIQUE` (`idUsers` ASC) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `regula`.`Projects`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `regula`.`Projects` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `regula`.`Projects` (
  `idProjects` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `ownerId` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `name` TEXT NOT NULL ,
  `date` DATE NOT NULL ,
  `time` TIME NOT NULL ,
  `place` TEXT NOT NULL ,
  `itemType` INT NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idProjects`) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `idProjects_UNIQUE` (`idProjects` ASC) ,
  INDEX `ownerId` (`ownerId` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `ownerId`
    FOREIGN KEY (`ownerId` )
    REFERENCES `regula`.`Users` (`idUsers` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `regula`.`ItemTypes`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `regula`.`ItemTypes` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `regula`.`ItemTypes` (
  `idItemTypes` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `prjId` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `parentId` INT UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `name` TEXT NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idItemTypes`) ,
  INDEX `prjId` (`prjId` ASC) ,
  INDEX `parentId` (`parentId` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `prjId`
    FOREIGN KEY (`prjId` )
    REFERENCES `regula`.`Projects` (`idProjects` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `parentId`
    FOREIGN KEY (`parentId` )
    REFERENCES `regula`.`ItemTypes` (`idItemTypes` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `regula`.`Reservation`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `regula`.`Reservation` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `regula`.`Reservation` (
  `idReservation` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `prjId` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `itemTypeId` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `userId` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idReservation`) ,
  INDEX `prjId` (`prjId` ASC) ,
  INDEX `itemTypeId` (`itemTypeId` ASC) ,
  INDEX `userId` (`userId` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `prjId`
    FOREIGN KEY (`prjId` )
    REFERENCES `regula`.`Projects` (`idProjects` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `itemTypeId`
    FOREIGN KEY (`itemTypeId` )
    REFERENCES `regula`.`ItemTypes` (`idItemTypes` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `userId`
    FOREIGN KEY (`userId` )
    REFERENCES `regula`.`Users` (`idUsers` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Error 121 means that there is a foreign key constraint error. Since you're using InnoDB, you can use `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` after running the failed query to get an explanation in the `LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR` section. Having run your SQL myself, I get this:

```
------------------------
LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
------------------------
101210 14:55:50 Error in foreign key constraint creation for table `regula`.`Reservation`.
A foreign key constraint of name `regula`.`prjId`
already exists. (Note that internally InnoDB adds 'databasename'
in front of the user-defined constraint name.)
Note that InnoDB's FOREIGN KEY system tables store
constraint names as case-insensitive, with the
MySQL standard latin1_swedish_ci collation. If you
create tables or databases whose names differ only in
the character case, then collisions in constraint
names can occur. Workaround: name your constraints
explicitly with unique names.
```

Basically, you need to give your prjId constraint name a unique name in the last table. Constraint/foreign key names are global to a database, so they cannot be reused in different tables. Just change the last

```
  CONSTRAINT `prjId`
```

to

```
  CONSTRAINT `prjId2`
```

Comment: You may need SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; Without the 'ENGINE' mysql was throwing syntax errors for me.

Comment: You're right, I've updated it. MySQL removed the old syntax starting in version 5.5.

Answer (score 3):

The error code 121 comes when you try to map the foreign key.

Basically it comes when your foreign key name already exists in the database.

For example:

```
ALTER TABLE `photokiosk`.`kiosk_event`
    ADD CONSTRAINT `event_booking_id`
    FOREIGN KEY `event_booking_id` (`event_booking_id`)
    REFERENCES `event_booking` (`event_booking_id`)
```

If foreign key with the name **event_booking_id** is already mapped with the other table.

To get rid of this issue, please change the foreign key name, not the column name.

Answer (score 0):

You will get this error message if you try to use a constraint name which already exists in the table.

Here 'prjId' already exists in table `regula`.`ItemTypes`. So, you can't use the same constraint name on table 'regula.reservation' again.