# #1005 - Can't create table './domain/actions.frm' (errno: 121) on empty DB

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to restore a client's DB because some problems with their hosting cause them to lose all information.  Now, I go to phpmyadmin and try to import the sql file but the following error appears:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `actions` (

`aid` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0' COMMENT  'Primary Key: Unique actions ID.',
`type` VARCHAR( 32 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '' COMMENT  'The object that that action acts on (node, user, comment, system or custom types.)',
`callback` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '' COMMENT  'The callback function that executes when the action runs.',
`parameters` LONGBLOB NOT NULL COMMENT  'Parameters to be passed to the callback function.',
`label` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0' COMMENT  'Label of the action.',
PRIMARY KEY (  `aid` )
) ENGINE = INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8 COMMENT =  'Stores action information.';

MySQL said: Documentation

#1005 - Can't create table './domain/actions.frm' (errno: 121)
```

I've read it has something to do with duplicated names, but since this DB is empty I can't see how could anything be duplicated, or how to delete it if there was.  How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, most suggestions are to rename the duplicated names, but since my DB seems to be empty I don't know how to go about it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412693/sql-error-code-1005-with-error-number-121 Try running the query given in the accepted answer. `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS`

Comment: I don't have the privileges to run queries, and I probably  won't be getting them soon. The hosting company suggested I disabled foreign key constraints, could that work?