# Mysql can't create table errno 121

Tags: mysql

Why am I getting this error? I don't have any foreign keys

```
drop table if exists t_issue;
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;SET storage_engine=INNODB;
CREATE TABLE `t_issue` (
`id_issue` int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
`fk_project` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`subject` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`estimated_due_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
`due_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
`done_ratio` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`fk_status` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`fk_assigned_to` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`fk_owner` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=innodb DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: Seems to work OK for me.

Comment: [It's working](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3d392).What error you are facing

Comment: I changed the name of the table to t_issue1 and the query works for that, for t_issue it doesen't. However I did a "Show tables" but no table named t_issue exists. What could the problem be?

Comment: @patentul check here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3d392/1

Comment: @patentul, Whats your problem, what kind of error you getting, if you can paste the error.

Comment: It is the same previous question from you: [*Mysql can't create table errno 121*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22712051/mysql-cant-create-table-errno-121)

Comment: @jmail: I'm getting Error Code: 1005. Can't create table 'ticket_tool.t_issue' (errno: 121)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ERROR: Error 1005: Can't create table (errno: 121)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12623651/error-error-1005-cant-create-table-errno-121)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

## Mysql can't create table errno 121

You will get this message if you are trying to add a constraint with a name that is already used somewhere else.

To check constraints, use the following SQL query:

```
SELECT
    constraint_name,
    table_name
FROM
    information_schema.table_constraints
WHERE
    constraint_type = 'FOREIGN KEY'
AND table_schema = DATABASE()
ORDER BY
    constraint_name;
```

Reference: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/425/error-creating-foreign-key-from-mysql-workbench

See also: [SQL - error code 1005 with error number 121](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412693/sql-error-code-1005-with-error-number-121)

Comment: I did this, none of the constraints resulted in the query are being used in my current query for generating this table

Comment: yes I did, One constraint indeed was being used, I replaced that, but it still does not work

Comment: Error Code: 1005. Can't create table 'ticket_tool.t_issue' (errno: 121)

Comment: Well I did try again, but without success, as I said I replaced the constraints that are used

Comment: (+1) for useful question, because Most of the person(stack over flowers) don't know this question, so, get the +1 for the useful question...

Comment: Note that the same error may result if you attempt to create a table having a unique key and a foreign key with the same name.  I say may, because one version of MySQL I tried allowed this table to be created, while an earlier version refused and reported the 121 error.

Comment: And how can you make it just generate a new random name for the constraint so the create succeeds?