# mysql error code 1005 errno 121

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE batchdata(
    batch int not null auto_increment,  
    rollNo int not null,
    fees float,
    startdate date,
    primary key (batch),
    foreign key (rollNo) references studentdata(rollNo) );
```

how to resolve this error?

Comment: Where did you define the `studentdata` table?

Comment: You can start solving it with a list of MySQL error codes. For example: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-messages-server.html.

Comment: Check that the fk complies with the conditions described in https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: It is already defined..

create table StudentData(
rollNo int primary key auto_increment unique,
name varchar(40) not null,
age int unsigned null
);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL - error code 1005 with error number 121](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412693/sql-error-code-1005-with-error-number-121)

Answer (score 1):

Error 121 means that there is a foreign key constraint error. Since you're using InnoDB, you can use `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` after running the failed query to get an explanation in the LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR section.

See this link for more details: [SQL - error code 1005 with error number 121](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412693/sql-error-code-1005-with-error-number-121)